# How to hide custom workflows for a particular role?

Tags: java, xml, alfresco

I am working with  roles and permission's.i have to create an permission that hides the created custom workflow's for perticular role.when i am adding this bean file and the wizard in xml i am not able to start the workflow at all .please let me know if any other way is there.



#### this is the bean file i have created

public List getResources()
   {
      this.resources = new ArrayList(4);

```
  UserTransaction tx = null;
  try
  {
     FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
     tx = Repository.getUserTransaction(context, true);
     tx.begin();

     for (String newItem : this.packageItemsToAdd)
     {
        NodeRef nodeRef = new NodeRef(newItem);
        if (this.getNodeService().exists(nodeRef))
        {
           // create our Node representation
           MapNode node = new MapNode(nodeRef, this.getNodeService(), true);
           this.browseBean.setupCommonBindingProperties(node);

           // add property resolvers to show path information
           node.addPropertyResolver("path", this.browseBean.resolverPath);
           node.addPropertyResolver("displayPath", this.browseBean.resolverDisplayPath);

           this.resources.add(node);
        }
        else
        {
           if (logger.isDebugEnabled())
              logger.debug("Ignoring " + nodeRef + " as it has been removed from the repository");
        }
     }

     // commit the transaction
     tx.commit();
  }
  catch (Throwable err)
  {
     Utils.addErrorMessage(MessageFormat.format(Application.getMessage(
           FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), Repository.ERROR_GENERIC), err.getMessage()), err);
     this.resources = Collections.<Node>emptyList();
     try { if (tx != null) {tx.rollback();} } catch (Exception tex) {}
  }

  return this.resources;
```

} 
**here is bean implimentatin**
protected void resetRichList()
   {
      if (this.packageItemsRichList != null)
      {
         this.packageItemsRichList.setValue(null);
         this.packageItemsRichList = null;
      }
   }

**this is the xml file** 

            
                
                    Collaborator

Answer (score 2):

I can answer this, but your question is too vague.

If I just look at the question, then it's very simpel --> Just create an evaluator which check on custom-workflow action.

Find the file web-client-config-workflow-actions.

Change or override this code:

```
    <action id="start_workflow">
            <label-id>start_workflow</label-id>
            <image>/images/icons/new_workflow.gif</image>
            <evaluator>org.alfresco.web.action.evaluator.StartWorkflowEvaluator</evaluator>
            <action>wizard:startWorkflow</action>
            <action-listener>#{WizardManager.setupParameters}</action-listener>
            <params>
               <param name="item-to-workflow">#{actionContext.id}</param>
            </params>
    </action>
```

Change this line:

```
<evaluator>org.alfresco.web.action.evaluator.StartWorkflowEvaluator</evaluator>
```

To your custom Java class and check on the right permission, or just add

```
<permissions>
    <permission allow="true">Your Role aka Write, Collaborator, etc</permission>
</permissions>
```

Comment: For info, `web-client-config-workflow-actions.xml` is in `tomcat\webapps\alfresco\WEB-INF\classes\alfresco` (in a default install of Alfresco Community 4.0.d)